# Replace first match of preg_match?

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match

I have a permalink like this:

`example.com/cyclone/2013/06/05/introduction/`

This post belongs to both categories 'cyclone' and 'weather' but 'cyclone' is taking over in this permalink.

I need to check if 'weather' is assigned to this post and then rewrite the permalink.

```
if( in_array( 'weather', $cats ) ) {
        $pattern = '#([^/]+)/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/([^/]+)/?#';
        if( preg_match( $pattern, $permalink, $matches ) ) {
            if( $matches[1] && $old_cat = get_category_by_slug( $matches[1] ) && 'weather' !== $matches[1] ) {
                preg_replace( '/' . $matches[1] . '/', $new_cat, $permalink );
                return $permalink;
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, $matches[1] isn't a valid 'pattern' to be used in preg_replace. How can I replace the first match of preg_match?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a preg_replace_callback function:

```
$permalink = preg_replace_callback('~[^/]++(?=\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/[^/]++)~',
    function ($m) use ($new_cat, $old_cat) {
        if ($old_cat == get_category_by_slug($m[0]) && 'weather' !== $m[0])
            return $new_cat;
    },
    $permalink);
```

Note that *preg_replace* and *preg_replace_callback* don't change the subject string but return the modified string.